# How to tell google this text is part of another article

Tags: html, seo, web-crawler, google-crawlers

After every article in my website there are previews for other articles. They are random previews.

The problem is the previews are really big: got headline, subheadline and 6 rows of text. Sometimes google thinks they are part of my article.

Is there any way to tell google that this div contains text from another article?

**preview example:**
[image: preview example]

Answer (score 0):

By using the appropriate semantic markup that HTML5 offers, user agents (like Google) would, in principle, be able to understand this; but that, of course, doesn’t necessarily mean that they (currently) support (all of) this.

- The teasers should be *outside* of the [`main` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-main-element).
  Signal: It’s not part of this page’s main content.
- The teasers should be in an [`aside` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-aside-element).
  Signal: It’s only "tangentially related" to the page’s content.
- Each teaser should be in its own [`article` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-article-element).
  Signal: It’s a self-contained item of content.
- Each teaser’s link (to the full article) should get the [`bookmark` link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#link-type-bookmark).
  Signal: The permalink URL of the teaser/article is not the same as the current page’s URL.
- (One could also consider using the [`blockquote` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element) for the parts taken over literally, i.e., in cases where the teaser doesn’t contain (slightly) different content, like a summary. But it depends on your understanding of your content, if you really quote here.)

However, that doesn’t stop Google to show parts of the teasers in their SERPs (if their algorithms deem it useful, get confused, or whatever). Without using some "hacks" (e.g., with JS or an `iframe`), it’s not possible nor intended to hide parts of the page for Google Search and their SERPs.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the preview article div in

```
<!--googleoff: all-->
<!--googleon: all>
```

That tells Google not to index that part of your page.

You can costumize the tag to your preference:

**index** — content surrounded by “googleoff: index” will not be indexed by Google

**anchor** — anchor text for any links within a “googleoff: anchor” area will not be associated with the target page

**snippet** — content surrounded by “googleoff: snippet” will not be used to create snippets for search results

**all** — content surrounded by “googleoff: all” are treated with all attributes: index, anchor, and snippet

([Source](https://perishablepress.com/tell-google-to-not-index-certain-parts-of-your-page/))

Comment: "That seems to be good only if you have Google Search appliance installed "